# How to replace the path with a custom variable in the visitor flow?

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to use Google Analytic's visitor flow to understand the behaviour of my visitors.

My current visitor flow looks like this:

[image: Visitor flow]

As you can see, my URL structure is not really friendly to this tool, and thus I'm having a hard time extracting any useful information from there.

I've seen that analytics.js allows us to send custom variables, including [overriding the path](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#overriding).

I guess that I could override the path to give all pages of the same type a common (fake) path, something like:

```
/restaurant/123/index => /restaurant
/restaurant/456/index => /restaurant

/restaurant/123/order => /order
/restaurant/456/order => /order
```

but I would be losing the potentially precious information that the original path represents.

Is it possible to send a *custom variable* to Google Analytics instead, and **have the visitor flow use the custom variable instead of the path** when displaying the above flow?

Comment: I'd have to look into it further, but you might be able to use two separate `pageview` functions if you want to do as you're saying and categorize them into a lump, but also preserve the original for granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully in the future this will be achievable with the recently launched page group feature, but right now I think you'll have to make a hack.

If preserving the original URL is important, I would recommend setting up a new view and then using filters to rewrite/aggregate the URLs.

AFAIK, you can't use custom dimensions in filters (yet), so you would have to set up a an advanced filter for each "type" of URL you want to rewrite.

For example:

```
Filter type:           Advanced
Field A:               Request URI
Field A pattern:       ^/restaurant/\d+/index
Output To:             Request URI
Output To value:       /restaurant
Field A required:      Yes
Override Output Field: Yes
```

Now all pageviews to `/restaurant/xxxxx/index` will be aggregated under `/restaurant` in your new view, but still be reported with the proper URL in the old one.